# Problems with radio button and button event

Tags: c#

I'm working on c# and I have a problem with a radio button.
I have a gridview a button and and a column radio button.
When I check one radio button, then I click on the button, the radio button will be unchecked.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

This is the code of radio button in aspx page:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton  ID ="radioButton1"  HeaderText="Main" runat="server" onclick = "RadioCheck(this);" AutoPostBack ="False" Checked="False" CausesValidation="True" />

        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value = '<%#Eval("id")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and this is the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#80FF00" Font-Size="Large" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Delete unselected rows" Width="200px" />
```

Comment: The button is outside the grid? Do you want to uncheck all radio buttons?

Comment: the button is outside..I want just that the radio button checked stays checked when I click a button